# Facebook PHP SDK Scope Request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to request above basic permissions for my facebook website app in PHP. I have the following code:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost:54321/xxxx.php');

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
}

if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

$params = array(
  'scope' => 'basic_info'
);

  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl($params) . '">Login</a>';
}
```

This provides a URL link, however when I click it, it redirects to a facebook URL and fails with a 500. If I remove `$params` from the getLoginURL, it functions fine. How do I use this to request more permissions?

Comment: `basic_info` permission does not exist any more in API v2, it has been replaced with `public_profile`.

Comment: And when you call getLoginURL $params are never set.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `getLoginUrl()` method accepts a numeric array of permissions. You are using an associative array. A correct usage looks like this: `$params = array('email','public_profile');`
2. As @WizKid pointed out, the `$params` array is being set in the first block of your `if ( isset( $session ) )` statement so it never gets passed to `getLoginUrl()`.
3. As @CBroe pointed out, `basic_info` is depricated in Graph 2.x and is now split into  `public_profile` and `user_friends`.